# Child taking full width of the body without breaking out of the flow

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need the CSS for the child which take full-width of the body but does not break out of the flow (without using Javascript). I already tried this:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```

But this makes the child break out of the flow. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/v5Mq4/
The height of the absolutely positioned child is variable. So margin-bottom or margin-top does not apply.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean break the flow? What does it do now?

Comment: The child elements that come after the absolutely positioned child takes its place as if its not in document flow. I want the absolutely positioned child to take its given height in the parent container.

Comment: What's your html look like? The middle/full width section can't be included in the flow because it breaks #parent's box boundary. Include what you've already written and not just arbitrary css.

Comment: @AlamKanak Hmmmm, is the height of the child fixed? Or does it change?

Comment: The height varies. It depends on the content inside. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/v5Mq4/

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning removes the element from the document flow.

You can do what you intend, but you'll have to fill in your layout by creating the same-size gap. You can do this by adding margin-bottom to the previous element.

Comment: But the height could be vary. I wouldn't know the height beforehand.

Comment: That's where JavaScript comes in.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by mixing the usage of relative and absolute divs.

CSS Classes

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: -100px;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

and the DIVS

```
<div width='100%' align='center'>
    <div class='relative'>
        <div class='absolute'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Plus you need another parent container (or the body) to be centering the contained elements.

Here's a jsFiddle with the solution in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/35vDd/

Cheers.